# Vitest -Unable to access the DOM inside a test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vite, vitest

I am new to front-end testing, and I am trying to get a good grasp on it.

In the process, inside one project, I am creating a test for a Vue component. I want to test that the behaviour of the code is correct (The component has code inside the `mounted()` hook that has to perform basically some checks and an API call).

I want to check that the code reaches one method. Previously to that, the code creates a click event listener to one element in the DOM.

My test emulates a click event (triggers it), but it cannot assert that the proper method has been called after the click event.

This is due to it not finding the element in the DOM to which it has to add the event listener. It seems that the code cannot find anything inside the document (using `.getElementById()`).

I wonder why, and how I would resolve this, since I have been stuck here for hours and I haven't found any solution that could work here, even when I have learned some interesting things in the process. I will leave a code example with the code structure I have built:

---

**Inside the component:**

```
<template>
   // ...
   <button id = "myButton">Add</button>
</template>
<script>
import { classInExternalScriptsFile } from "@/scripts/externalScriptsFile ";

let classIESF = new classInExternalScriptsFile();

export default {
  methods: {
    setup: function () {
      classIESF.setupMethod();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setupMethod();
  },
};
</script>
```

---

**Inside the scriptsFile**

```
export class classInExternalScriptsFile {
  setupMethod() {
     let myButton = document.getElementById("myButton") // <-- getElementById() returns a null here

    if (typeof myButton !== "undefined" && myButton !== null) {
       myButton.onclick = () => { // <-- The test code complains because it cannot enter here
        // Some lines...
        this.mySuperMethod()
      }
    }
  }

  mySuperMethod() {
     // API call etc.
  } 
}
```

---

**Inside the .spec.js test file:**

```
// imports...

import { classInExternalScriptsFile } from "@/scripts/externalScriptsFile.js";

describe("description...", () => {

    const mySuperMethodMock = vi
      .spyOn(classInExternalScriptsFile.prototype, "mySuperMethod")
      .mockImplementation(() => {});

  test("That the button performs x when clicked", () => {
    let wrapper = mount(myComponent, {
        props: ...,
      });


      let myButton = wrapper.find('[test-id="my-button"]');
      myButton.trigger("click");

      
      expect(mySuperMethodMock).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- The test fails here
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no comp template so it's unknown what are you testing. Direct DOM access results in poorly testable code

Comment: What do you mean with "Direct DOM access"? The template just has a list and an add button to add something to that list.

Comment: I mean that this `document.getElementById`  shouldn't generally exist in well-written Vue code. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's expected in code that there's an element with `myButton` id, but it's not shown where it exists

Comment: did you got any answer for this, I'm also struck at this point @S.Dre